# Client-Side Save Event in Edit Mode

Tags: 2013, content-editor-web-part, jsom, edit

Is there any client-side event I can listen to when a user saves a page?

I know how to detect the edit mode and I could add event listeners to save/check-in buttons, but it would be better to listen an event for this.

Or how do I find out if a user just saved/checked-in a page?